# How to retrieve data from very large datasets with optional parameters?

Tags: c#, sql

I have an app that retrieves data requested by the user. All parameters except `Type` are optional. If a parameter is not specified, all items are retrieved. If it is specified, only items corresponding that parameter are retrieved. For example, here I retrieve products by year of release (-1 is the default value, if the user hasn't specified one):

```
var products = context.Products.Where(p => p.type == Type).ToList();
  if (!(Year == -1))
    products = products.Where(p => p.year == Year).ToList();
```

This works perfectly fine for some of the years. E.g., if I search 2001, I get all entries needed. But since `products` has a limited size and only retrieves 1500 entries, later years are simply not retrieved, not in the `products` list, and it comes up as no data for that year, even though there is data in the DB.

How can I get around this problem?

Comment: Perhaps the would be an optimization to not ToList all the time, as this will trigger the query to run. If you just where where where then EF will build the query string without hitting the db meaning that when ToList is finally called the db can do more of the filtering

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Ill add a bit more background for you as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the nice things about deferred execution on LINQ is it can help make code that has variable filtering rules a lot more neat and readable. If you're not sure what deferred execution is, in a nutshell it's a mechanism that only runs the LINQ query when you ask for the results rather than when you make the statements that comprise the query.

In essence this means we can have code like:

```
//always adults 
var p = person.Where(x => x.Age > 18);

//we maybe filter on these
if(email != null)
  p = p.Where(x => x.Email == email);
if(socialSN != null)
  p = p.Where(x => x.SSN == socialSN);

var r = p.ToList();  //the query is only actually run now
```

The multiple calls to `where` here are cumulative; they will conceptually build a where clause but not execute the query until ToList is called. At this point, if a database is in use then the db sees the query with all its Where clauses and can leverage indexes and statistics

If we were to use ToList after every Where, then the first Where would hit the db and it's whole dataset would download to the client app, and the runtime would set about converting an enumerable to a list (a lot of copying and memory allocating). The subsequent Where would filter the list in the client app, enumerating it but then converting it to a list again - the big problem being its done in the memory of the client app as some naive unindexed loop, and all those millions of dollars of r&d Microsoft poured into making their SQL Server query optimizer pull huge amounts of data very quickly, are wasted :)

Consider also that that first clause in my example set- Age>18 could be huge; a million people of a spread of ages over age 12, for example - A large amount of data is true for that predicate. Email or SSN would be a far smaller dataset, probably indexed etc. It's a contrived example sure but hopefully well illustrates the point about performance; by ToList()ing too early we end up downloading too much data